# Which is the correct way to transfer values between unions?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, unions

If you have:

```
typedef union value {
    int i;
    float f;
} VALUE;
VALUE a, b;
```

if you know the type of a, should you do

```
b.i = a.i;
b.f = a.f;
```

or

```
if(a_type == INT)
    b.i = a.i;
if(a_type == FLOAT)
    b.f = a.f;
```

Comment: what's `a`? what's `b`? what's `a_type`? please show a [mcve].

Comment: No, you can only know what to fill in by passing another parameter.

Comment: in general, your code would be wrong if the member `i` was the active member of `a`. If you really don't know which member is active, you'll have a problem, but you could still use `memcpy` like `memcpy(&b, &a, sizeof b);`

Comment: @mpez0: *all bit patterns are valid for ints* is not something the C Standard guarantees. On pathological architectures such as older Cray computers, this approach would fail. Just use `memcpy(&b, &a, sizeof b);`

Answer (score 6):

Just use `b = a` unless there is a particular reason not to, such as that the union occasionally contains a large amount of data, and you want to optimize the assignment for cases when it contains only a small amount.

Per C 2011 [N1570] 6.5.16.1 1, one of the acceptable situations for simple assignment is:

> the left operand has an atomic, qualified, or unqualified version of a structure or union type compatible with the type of the right.

Per 6.2.7 1:

> Two types have compatible type if their types are the same.

(Per 6.2.6.1 6, “The value of a structure or union object is never a trap representation, even though the value of a member of the structure or union object may be a trap representation.”)

Answer (score 1):

The most correct probably is (assuming the the same type)

```
memcpy(&b, &a, sizeof(b));
```

Comment: correct, suggest to remove the parantheses around `b` as the `sizeof` argument ... they would only be needed for a type name.

Comment: What about `b = a` ?

Comment: @FelixPalmen I like them. It is my style.

Comment: Yep - no space right. But it was as I remember about the sizeof.

Comment: well, yes, the typical style for `sizeof` is to use a single space when the argument is an expression and use parantheses without a space when the argument is a type name. But write whatever you like if you insist :D

Comment: I write it this way 30 years - something wrong with it, any dangers?

Comment: @FelixPalmen: actually, I would recommend the extra parentheses to enhance readability in `sizeof(*b) * 10`

Comment: @PeterJ_01: no dangers at all, actually safer if you work anywhere close to Linus Torvalds: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9629461

Comment: @chqrlie wouldn't `(sizeof *b) * 10` better reflect the structure of this expression?

Comment: @FelixPalmen: not in my opinion, but really just a question of style.

Comment: @FelixPalmen it is much easier to see what is sizeof-ed. At least for me (and it  is the clinching argument for me and I do not force anyone to the same). Argument that people will think that sizeof is a function is silly. They may think the same about macros.

Comment: @chqrlie well, I had to giggle on that LT opinion ;) "*But "sizeof()" really **is** a function.*" <- no, it isn't. But LT has "strong opinions", as always :D

Comment: @PeterJ_01 indeed, still it's an operator, so when adding "redundant" parantheses (which is a **good** thing if it helps to make precedence obvious), it makes more sense IMHO to put them around the whole `sizeof` expression. Whatever, there's no **definitive** C style guide, so people can of course do what they consider good.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I do not have anything against someones style if it is clearer, easier .... for that person. You like to force your personal opinions as a the only truth and axiom. Some guys like slim girls another  not. Who is right?

Comment: @PeterJ_01 I never **forced** you to follow my suggestions, it more looks like you're allergic to suggestions. Yes, I like my style better for the logic I explained, you're free to follow a different logic.

Comment: @FelixPalmen So what is the reason of your first comment: `suggest to remove the parantheses around b as the sizeof argument ... they would only be needed for a type name.`?

Comment: I'm not agree this is a question of style, when I see a sizeof with extra parenthesis, My sense are awake because I only do that when I can't use a variable name. So when I use parenthesis I highlight the fact that I don't use variable and that I should check if the type is correct. And sometime linus is plenty wrong ;)

Answer (score 0):

The Standard does not specify in what cases the storage associated with an aggregate may be accessed via a member-access lvalue of non-character type.  If a union member `member1` is the largest type in a union and has no trap representations, a quality compiler should be able to handle operations like

```
objectOfMemberType = someUnion.member1;
someUnion.member1 = valueOfMemberType;
```

A quality compiler should also have no problem with constructs like:

```
memberType *p = &someUnion.member1;
*p = valueOfMemberType;
```

As the Standard is written, it imposes no requirements upon the behavior of either construct if the member is of non-character type, and thus the only ways to do anything with unions without invoking UB are to either use lvalue of union type to copy the entire contents of a union, use lvalues of character type to accesses pieces of the union, or use functions like `memcpy`.  Accessing union contents directly through member lvalues seems mostly reliable in gcc and clang (I think the cases I've found where it doesn't are unintentional bugs) but neither gcc nor clang seems to be designed to reliably support any use of union member pointers, even when the usage *immediately* follows the act of taking the address [as shown above].

Given the way the C Standard is written, it's hard to really determine a "correct" way of transferring values between unions, since most kinds of code which would employ unions in useful fashion invoke UB.  Which approach is best depends upon which forms of UB one is willing to trust one's compiler to process sensibly.